# CSS Box Shadow on a div gets hidden by other divs

Tags: html, css

I have two boxes, they are stacked vertically. I want the top div to have a box shadow on its bottom edge. The top box's shadow is hidden behind the bottom box.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use:

either

```
#first{
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
```

or

```
#second{
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

PS: Sorry for the previous answer mistakes. - Example shown: http://jsfiddle.net/fdezluis96/FRQKA/

Good luck!

Comment: It should be `position: relative`, not `absolute`, and there's no need for such a ridiculously high `z-index`.

Comment: Sure you can, here you have a JSFiddle showing both options, good luck - http://jsfiddle.net/6CUqd/2/. I updated the answer to fit your requirement @DonnyP

Comment: Thanks Luis - very comprehensive answer bt I've only got 1 upvote :)

Comment: Thanks. Why is `position: relative` required?

Comment: @Sung Won Cho because z-index only works on positionned elements. `position:absolute`, `position:relative`, `position:fixed` or `position:sticky` would have the same effects on the box-shadow, but different results on the box itself. With any other `position:` the z-index will not be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Or just add a margin-bottom: 10px or something to top div

Comment: That pushes the bottom div down, which I highly doubt is desired behavior.

Comment: can't push down the bottom box